# A sufficient condition for $\eta$-quotients to be modular forms

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $f$ be the form :
$$f(\tau)=\prod_{M\mid N}{\eta(M\tau)^{a_M}} \quad (\tau \in \mathcal{H})$$
Generally, we said that $f$ is an $\eta$-quotient when $(a_M)$ is a sequence of integers.  One can find conditions on $(a_M)$ such that $f$ is a modular form of weight $k$ invariant under $\Gamma_0(N)$ (with a charactere $\chi$) :
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{M\mid N}{a_M}=k$$
$$\forall c \mid N, \quad\frac{1}{24}\sum_{M\mid N}{\frac{\operatorname{gcd}(c,M)^2}{M}a_M} \in \textbf{Q}_{+}$$
(reference : http://www.beck-shop.de/fachbuch/leseprobe/9783642161513_Excerpt_001.pdf). But with those conditions, for which reason must we impose $\left\{a_M\right\}\in \textbf{Z}$ and not $\left\{a_M\right\}\in \textbf{Q}$ ?

Thanks !

Comment: Useful Refs: [Newman 1958](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-9/3/373.extract),
and Th. 2 in a [Kilford 2011 preprint](http://uk.arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0701/0701478v1.pdf).
It is attributed to [Ligozat 1975](http://smf4.emath.fr/en/Publications/Memoires/1975/43/html/smf_mem_43.html), though Kilford's version seems to be more general. In contrast to Newman, Kilford's theorem does not ensure entirety though.

Comment: Thanks for your useful references ! Nevertheless, I've just find my answer... which let me with an other question. I edited the topic.

Comment: How would you interpret $\eta(M\tau)^{1/2}$? Which square root will you take?

Comment: I had quoted from Köhler in a too-early answer until I noticed that you do not seem to allow for a multiplier system, i. e. some 24th root of unity in the transformation identity. To impose conditions that ensure that the multiplier becomes $1$, you need to apply the Ligozat-like theorem in the above Kilford preprint and pay attention to eq. (5). I suppose that Newman has properly combined all those conditions.

Comment: I has taken me some time to recognize what has triggered @GerryMyerson's comment: Stabilo, do you want to ask about the right-hand sides of some conditions to be in $\mathbb{Z}$ or are you really meaning to ask about fractional exponents $\{a_M\}$? As currently written, it's the latter, but you may want the former.

Comment: My question can be expressed as the following : can we find $f$ an $\eta$-quotient for which $(a_M)$ is not a sequence of integers (in terms of the usual branch of the complex logarithm) but $f$ is holomorphic at all the cusps of $\Gamma$, and satisfies the usual transformation of weight $k$ under the congruent subgroup $\Gamma$ ?
In fact, all authors consider $\left\{a_M\right\}$ to be in $\textbf{Z}$ but it's not trivial for me...

Comment: Am I clear or not ? (I'm a french user and I apologize for my english mistakes)

Comment: True, nothing hinders you from defining $\eta^a$ properly and working out the details (changing the $1/24$ and $1/2$ accordingly etc). Valid question. But isn't it heretic to run against the "one eta fits all needs" image? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sidenote: This answer involves guessing, and I am not particularly fond of it. In fact, I had deleted it, but some users apparently have found it better than nothing and have voted successfully for undeletion. Well then.*

Why only integer exponents?

- Nothing hinders you from choosing $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and properly defining a power of the normalized modular discriminant just as the Dedekind eta function has been defined using $a=\frac{1}{24}$. The discriminant is finite and nonzero on $\mathbb{H}$, therefore its fractional powers have no branch points in $\mathbb{H}$, and you get a proper one-valued function as a result.
- Of course, the real period of the resulting function then changes to the (reduced) denominator of $a$, but such considerations have already been mastered for the Dedekind eta, and one could again work out all the necessary details: The new multiplier system for example.
- At least the weight formula you have mentioned would carry over analogously.

But:

- Other parts may not carry over. For example, [Newman 1958](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-9/3/373.extract), in working out the $\Gamma_0(N)$ modular forms criteria for eta quotients (presumably not being so lenient as to allow nontrivial multiplier systems), had to distinguish between $N$ coprime to $6$ and the more complicated general case. Expect such things to become more complicated when the denominator of $a$ has factors other than $2$ and $3$.
- If the denominator of $a$ does not divide $24$, the $q$-series for $(q^{-1}\Delta)^a(\tau) = \prod_{n=0}^\infty(1-q^n)^{24a}$, where $q=\exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau)$, no longer has integer-only coefficients.
  Now, many concrete investigations work with comparisons of truncated power series, or examine arithmetic properties such as multiplicativity, and having to deal with fractions there would be, well, uhm, not exactly a show stopper (I suppose), but at least nasty. Most researchers would not wrestle with a pig without good reason.

I suppose those are the main reasons.