# Generalization of the discriminant function to other level groups?

Tags: modular-forms

The discriminant function $\Delta(z) := q\prod (1 - q^n)^{24}$ is a cusp form for $SL(\mathbb{Z})$ of weight $12$. Are there any generalizations of these cusp forms for other level groups $\Gamma_0(N)$?

Comment: There are the $\Delta(dz)$ for divisors $d$ of $N$… other forms have explicit representations using $\eta$ ($\eta(z)^{11}\eta(11z)$, I think?). See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992540/a-sufficient-condition-for-eta-quotients-to-be-modular-forms

Comment: What sort of generalization are you looking for? There are lots of cusp forms out there.